# How can I make EclipsePDT autocomplete when using Silex config scripts?

Tags: php, eclipse, silex, eclipse-pdt

I hope you can help me !

**In words :** I work with a silex project that register DAOs via the share function. When I code and reuse theses DAO, I can not benefit from autocompletion and documentation, as I access it via an "array".

**In code :**

I have a series of DAOs registered like this in a `app.php` file (that is not a PHP Object, just a script that is required from my index.php). It configures the application, including services and DAOs :

```
$app ['dao.admin'] = $app->share ( function ($app) {
    return new AdminDAO ( $app );
} );
```

I access my DAOs functions with a `$app['dao.admin']->function()` like piece of code, and EclipsePDT do not provide any completion/phpdoc.

My structure :
`index.php` requires the autoload, `dev.php` or `prod.php` according to environment, `app.php`, then `routes.php`

```
Project
- app
  - config
    - dev.php 
    - prod.php
  - app.php
  - routes.php
- src 
  - Controller
    - *
  - DAO
    - *
  - Domain
    - *
  - Form
    - *
  - Utils
    - *
- var
  - *
- views
  - *
- web
  - index.php
  - public
    - *
```

**My config :**

- PHP
- Eclipse Mars.2 PDT
- Modules for eclipse :

  - Symfony feature
  - Twig editor feature
  - Eclipse IDE for PHP Devlopers
  - Github, markdown, makegood, JSON, etc...

**My questions :**

1. Is there any way to benefit from the doc I (painfully...) wrote ?
2. Is that way of doing a best practice ? If not, what practice should I use ? ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: try phpstorm https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ i use it and by my the auto complicazion works very well

Comment: Hi ! Thanks ! A free tool would be great... PhpStorm require an annual/monthly fee if I remember right ?

Comment: yeah sure :/ it was also a hard choose... i tried it for 30 days... now using it since 2 years...